# Does websocket not work with IWebBrowser2::Navigate?

Tags: websocket, iwebbrowser2

I am writing small html websocket application. This html page works fine at IE window but if same page is tried to open using IWebBrowser2::Navigate then it throws an error "WebSocket is undefined" in standard java script error message box. 
Following is sample javascript code:

```
function myFunction()
{

    ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + "127.0.0.1"+ "8070" +"/" + "NSCOMString");
}
```

Could you please let me whether websocket is implemented inside the navigate method?

Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IWebBrowser2 control by default runs in compatibility mode, see [this article on the IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx) for details on how to circumvent this behavior.

Comment: Setting correct elevation value and <!DOCTYPE html> in first line in html perfectly worked for me.  Thanks Eddy.